# change date format in input type "text" html

Tags: html, date, input, text, format

I need to change the date format to 2018-09-23 but now it shows date as 1818-09-23.

```
<input  name="start" id="datepicker1" type="text" value="<?php echo(set_value('start') ? set_value('start') : date('yy-m-d')); ?>"  class="form-control">
```

Is there any possible way to get the date format as 2018-09-23 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
<input  name="start" id="datepicker1" type="text" value="<?php echo(set_value('start') ? set_value('start') : date('Y-m-d')); ?>"  class="form-control">
```

Or in a more logical format:

```
<input  name="start" id="datepicker1" type="text" value="<?php echo(set_value('start') ? set_value('start') : date('m-d-Y')); ?>"  class="form-control">
```